# Why do I need to use a Class Instance for Self to automatically pass?

Tags: python-3.x

With the following class

```
class MyClass():
  "A random class"
  def __init__(self, var1=None, var2=None):
    self.var1 = var1
    self.var2 = var2
    
  def isVar1(self, var):
    if self.var1==var: print(True)
    else: print(False)
```

If I follow with

```
oneTwo = MyClass(1, 2)
oneTwo.isVar1(1)
```

No error is raised, but when I write

```
MyClass(1, 2)
MyClass.isVar1(1)
```

I get the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    MyClass.isVar1(1)
TypeError: isVar1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var'
```

And if I set `MyClass.isVar1(None, 1)` I just get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    MyClass.isVar1(None, 1)
  File "main.py", line 8, in isVar1
    if self.var1==var: print(True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'var1'
```

Why is this? Wouldn't the Class by default pass itself? When I have `oneTwo = MyClass(1, 2)` it will pass itself as Self. However, in this example, I pass the Class as itself and it works with no problem.

```
MyClass.__init__(MyClass, 1, 2)
MyClass.isVar1(MyClass, 1)
```

Could someone explain this to me? Or if I'm doing something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is the *instance* of the current object, i.e. the object on whose data you want to operate. When you call `oneTwo.isVar1(1)` then the `oneTwo` instance will be assigned to `self`.

Conversely, when you call `MyClass.isVar1(1)` then there is no instance (only the class) so you should only call *class methods* this way. These don't define the `self` parameter because they only get passed the method arguments - that's why you see the "missing required argument" error.

Passing `None` as the first parameter also doesn't work for the simple reason that then `self` gets assigned `None` which doesn't have a `var1` property that you try to access inside the method.

What you could do is pass an instance explicitly using `MyClass.isVar1(oneTwo, 1)`. That will work but it's cumbersome. Essentially, the assignment of the instance to the first method parameter when calling `instance.method()` is syntactic sugar offered by Python.

Read more about classes in the [Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)